# HTTP Error: 403, Permission iam.serviceAccounts.create is required to perform this operation on project "X" FIREBASE

Tags: firebase, github, cmd

I created a project in firebase, then I made them commands:

```
firebase login
firebase init
```

I associated it with my Github and finally

```
firebase deploy
```

from project "X" and it worked normally, then, I deleted project y from Github and Firebase and when I try to deploy from a new or different project I get the following error:

```
  HTTP Error: 403, Permission iam.serviceAccounts.create is required to perform this operation on project "X"
```

You can see the error here:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the output there is a default project in your .firebaserc file located in the directory you choosed to initialize the project.

The first thing you need to do is to delete the Secret in Github that you shared with Firebase in your previous deploy.

Go to your Github Project:

```
your-project > Settings > Secrets >  FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_ID
```

And remove it.

Then open the file .firebaserc and be sure that the default project is pointing to your current project ID:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "id_of_previous_project"
  },
```

After editing property:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "id_of_current_project"
  },
```

Then run the script again to get the initial configuration. If the error continues when you deploying or during the initialization execute this command

```
firebase use --add
```

This change the default project that Firebase Cli use in a directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! i was looking for that!